# Away goals rules in soccer

Tags: rules, football

I have a question about the away/home goals.

In soccer,

- I lost a game away 2 - 0.
- I won the game at home 3 - 1.

Did I win ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Well, it depends on the rules of the competition! But if as per your title, you're concerned about away goals, then your team will have lost:

- The primary factor is always<sup>1</sup> total number of goals scored across the two legs. In this case, you're tied 3-3.
- The tiebreaker is then number of goals scored in the away leg. In this case, it's 0-1 to your opponents.

  1. At least in every two-legged competition I've ever heard of.

Comment: This is effectively how it ends up working. The actual text on page 54 of the current Laws of the Game is, however, "Competition rules may provide that where teams play each other home and away, if the aggregate score is equal after the second match, any goals scored at the ground of the opposing team will count double."

Comment: @studro Ah, I didn't realise the only away goals, extra time and penalties were "approved" as methods for splitting a tied match. I'll try and update the answer to include that sometime today.

Answer (score 3):

In the major leagues that use a two-legged knock-out system, such as the UEFA Champions League and the UEFA Europa League, the winner is determined as follows:

1. Total number of goals scored in both legs.
2. Number of away goals scored.

If this still does not produce a winning, a 2x15 minutes overtime is played. Throughout history several rules have applied to it ([golden goal, silver goal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_goal#Association_football)), however currently the rules are as follows:

- Overtime (2x15 minutes) has to be completed fully.
- If no goals have been scored during overtime, the game will turn to a [penalty shootout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penalty_shoot-out_(association_football))
- The team that scored most goals in overtime wins
- If both teams scored the same number of goals in overtime, the second leg away team wins.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you lost. After all your goals are added up, from both away and home games, the team with the most number of total goals will have won. If the total goals are equal, the team with the most away goals will win. The other team has 1 away goal, while you have none. Since the totals are equal, the other team is the winner.

Answer (score 0):

Depends which competition you're talking about, for example:

- **UEFA Champions League/UEFA Europa League:** For example, these two competitions have the away goal rule. So, if you are talking about these two competitions the **answer is NO**. You lose, because you suffered one home goal against and scored none away.
- **CONMEBOL Libertadores/Sudamericana:** These two competitions are organized by Conmebol (South America) and they don't have the away goal rule. So you draw the game 3-3 and in this specific case, you're going to extra time.